# Callback function syntax in Javascirpt

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

Guys i am a newbie in Javascript and i really need your help.

```
const f = ()=>{
    
}

const y = f(()=>{

})
```

What does this code do ? Why we write *y function* this way instead of doing like this.

```
const y = f()=>{

}
```

Comment: It's impossibly to tell you *exactly* why it's written that way because you didn't post the code for `f()`, but the difference is that `f(() => { ... })` **calls** the function `f()` and passes it some function, while your version does not. The outer `( )` make the first version a function call.

Answer (score 2):

`const y = f(()=>{})` passes an arrow function as the first argument to the function `f` and stores the return value of `f` in the variable `y`. Passing functions to other functions is commonly used for callbacks.

```js
const f = arg => {
  console.log('first argument to f', arg);
  return "return value";
}
const y = f(()=>{});
console.log(y);
```

Comment: Thanks my friend for the  great explaination.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is invalid. So you cannot write a function like that

```
const y = f()=>{

}
```

The reason the code `const y = f(()=>{})` is written like that is because `f` is a function, hence the `f()`. You're calling `f` with the first argument being an anonymous function. `f` will do something with that function, as with any other function argument.

That's called passing a "callback" as an argument. You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)

The example from MDN:

```js
function greeting(name) {
  alert(`Hello, ${name}`);
}

// this would be your `f` function
function processUserInput(callback) {
  const name = prompt("Please enter your name.");
  callback(name);
}

processUserInput(greeting);
```

The code `const f = ()=>{}` is a normal function called `f`.